# Nifi convert UTC to unix time

Tags: datetime, apache-nifi, utc, unix-timestamp

I have a flowfile attribute which is a UTC datetime in the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

I need to convert this to a unix timestamp.

How can this be done? I know its possible to convert Unix to the above format using Jolt:

"time": "${time:format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}"

however, im not sure how to do this in reverse?

Comment: toDate():toNumber()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with attributes in this way uses the NiFi Expression Langauge (not Jolt).

See the docs here https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html

```
${time:format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}
```

Uses Expression Language to format the `time` attribute to the given SimpleDateFormat string.

```
${time:toNumber()}
```

Uses Expression Language to convert the given Date object to Epoch Millis.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#tonumber